# mysql MAX() returns 0 instead of actual value

Tags: php, mysql

The following code returns `0` instead of the biggest number from the row `order_id`

```
if ($result_oid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(order_id) AS order_id FROM $table")) {
  $result_oid->execute();
  $obj = $result_oid->get_result()->fetch_object();
  $oid_o = $obj->id;
  $result_oid->close();
  $oid = $oid_o + 1;
}
```

Here is a working example using the PHP `mysql` instead of `mysqli` (with the same mysql database):

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pwd) or die ("Couldn't connect to MySQL database.");

mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No Database found!");

$query = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(order_id) FROM airsale_list');
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM);
$max_order_id = $result[0];
$max_order_id = (int)$max_order_id;
$oid = $max_order_id++;
echo "<h4>order_id: $oid</h4>";

mysql_close();
```

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `airsale_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc_small` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `price` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EUR',
  `total_time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engine_time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prop_time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exterior` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interior` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avionics` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_info` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=103;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? It doesn't select the MAX(order_id)? What does your table look like?

Comment: you can't dynamically pass the table name

Comment: Sorry I'm tired thats why I forgot to point out the exact failure. It gives me a 0 as result when i call it from result_oid[0] and then I add 1 so the final value of oid is 1.

Comment: Why would you need to know this?

Comment: See error logs if you see any issues or use mysql_error()..

Comment: Why shouldn't I be able to pass the table name in a var? No real sense to me that comment

Comment: @web-nomad no errors given. Used mysql_error, it actually does the query the result of the query is just 0 which is to me a mysql query typo? But I can't see where I had a typo in the query, isnt it?

Comment: Are there no rows in the table?  You may be getting null back.

Comment: There are a couple of rows already

Comment: @Jeff whenever I use the mysql_query code I am getting NULL back. The query seems alright, what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you checking the result of execute?  Try hardcoding the table name to eliminate some possible errors.  NULL may mean no rows or it may mean the php object doesn't exist.  Its hard to tell without some output of the errors from the query.

Comment: @Jeff I just got back to this project and tried my old version. It worked perfectly fine, I posted the code above to show the working example. Now the changes to mysqli-functions should be easy, but whenever I do this it doesn't work anymore and stops when I execute the query. Any ideas to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `$obj->order_id` instead of `$obj->id` since you are grabbing the maximum value as order_id in the query.

```
if ($result_oid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(order_id) AS order_id FROM $table")) {
    $result_oid->execute();
    $obj = $result_oid->get_result()->fetch_object();
    $oid_o = $obj->order_id;
    $result_oid->close();
    $oid = $oid_o + 1;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be one typo but it still doesn't work with the code you posted. It also doesn't return errors because the browser wont continue to calc the code after this query

Comment: If the browser seems to stop, you probably have a PHP Fatal Error. Check your web server's error log.

Comment: The problem is the query when I use it with mysqli. This far I know, because when I use the other query it works but it will return the wrong ID. So it is definately a typo in the code because I use mysql $link->query($query) with another query afterwards and this works when i comment out the MAX-query

Comment: What do you get when you do `"SELECT * FROM $table"`? We can debug more depending on how that works with your code.

Comment: $table = "airsale_list";

SELECT * FROM airsale_list is returning all datas from the rows:
id (PRIMARY), cat, title, desc_small, .., order_id

Comment: If this is what you wanted to know?

Comment: If the same code with a different query gives you the expected results, there is probably an issue with your query. We'd probably need to see the table definition.

Comment: The problem is, it worked with the same code before..
If i use var_dump i get NULL from $max_order_id = $result_oid[0]; var_dump($max_order_id);